# Comparing date gaps in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, date

I have a collection with only one record in MongoDB:

```
> db.tabMessages.find( )

{ "tabId" : ObjectId("52a26579dc05b7a660ee12b1"),
  "fromUserId" : ObjectId("52a0ff959cad3f55275bd790"),
  "added" : ISODate("2013-12-07T00:02:42.490Z"), 
  "_id" : ObjectId("52a265a2dc05b7a660ee12ba") }
```

I want to delete "expired" tab messages. The query that comes to mind is:

```
db.tabMessages.find( { added: { $lte: ISODate() - ( 15 * 60000 )  } } )
```

This should delete all entries older than 15 minutes. However... it doesn't.
To make this work, I have to write:

```
db.tabMessages.find( { added: { $lte: new Date( ISODate() - ( 15 * 60000 ) ) } } )
```

It looks like Mongo converts the ISODate() object into a timestamp when I do ISODate() - ( 15 * 60000 ), and that at that point any comparison with date objects stored on the database will simply fail.

Now... am I going insane, or is this what's *actually* going on? If that is the case, I am thinking of storing everything as a UTC timestamp instead and avoid any messy problems like these.

Ideas?

*NOTE: I am after a non-mongo specific answer, if one exists. Using Mongo's TTL or Mongo's ISODate-specific methods is not really an option as I am accessing the DB with an abstraction layer and I need queries to work regardless*

Comment: So what exactly are you looking for. That a person will write the query for you in some magic abstraction layer (which no one has any idea how it looks like), that work regardless of any abstraction layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, in a query:

```
db.tabMessages.find({ 
    added: { 
       $lte: ISODate().setTimestamp(ISODate().getTimestamp() - ( 15 * 60000 )) 
    } 
});
```

Another way is set a TTL to the collection, and mongo will make the work for you:

```
db.tabMessages.ensureIndex( { "added": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 900000 } )
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

Comment: Sorry, I am actually running the query from NodeJS. I used the Mongo Shell here only to simplify as much as possible my question...

Comment: I am using a DB layer to use Mongo (simpledblayer, I wrote it myself). So, potentially I'd be making queries with MySql, MongoDB, counchdb... I was after a non-mongo specific answer (sorry, I didn't specify it)